# How to make table with 2 parameters

Tags: tables

I want to make a table that is for "parameters vs group" as in the image below:

[image]

Basically i want to show the dependence on the "parameters" (energy,correlation,random) versus "group size".

I am not used to make tables so I am open for other table formats.

Comment: have you read any introductions to LaTeX? take a look at https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf, page 46

Answer (score 2):

I like the `booktabs` package.  It provides `\midrule` and `\cmidrule` which have more generous spacing than `\hline` and `\cline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}rrrr@{}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{group} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Parameters} \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{energy} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{correlation} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{random} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    2 & 4 & 5 & 4 \\
    4 & 5 & 54 & 4 \\
    8 & 45 & 4 & 2 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{description}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have looked for templates in the internet but didn't find ones that suit me. Thanks for the link, i will try to read some about it, but I am under time pressure right now. ;) However i would also like to add a caption for the table but it didn't work: I got error that it is outside float.

Comment: \caption{description}

Comment: @Bob1990 See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I admire the `siunitx` package. It provides besides other also nice column formatting. And with it also compatible old good `mdwtab`  ...

[image]

Above table uses `booktabs` and `siunitx`, bottom one is made with use of `mdwtab` and `siunitx:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mdwtab,siunitx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{S[table-format=2]} }
    \toprule
{group} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Parameters}            \\
  \midrule
        & {energy}  &  {correlation}    &  {random} \\
  \cmidrule{2-4}
  2     &   4       &    5              &   4       \\
  4     &   5       &   54              &   4       \\
  8     &  45       &    4              &   2       \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{| *{4}{S[table-format=2] |} }
    \hlx{hv}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Parameters}            \\
    \hlx{vhv}
{group} & {energy}  &  {correlation}    &  {random} \\
    \hlx{vhv}
  2     &   4       &    5              &   4       \\
  4     &   5       &   54              &   4       \\
  8     &  45       &    4              &   2       \\
    \hlx{vh}
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try to read more about it. :)

Comment: The overall code indentation seems a little bit broken in your example.  (still +1)

Comment: @HenriMenke, in which sense? Enlighten me, please. I like to improve my code writing :-)

Comment: @Zarko Like [this](http://hastebin.com/ayuhiwuqil.tex) for example.  The consensus is to indent by two spaces inside an environment.  While sometimes nice, aligning tabulated material in the source file is uncommon.